# Map Reduce in Hadoop Counting problems

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, reducers

i m doing something on map reduce . For example i have some data set with the following

node_id node_id weight

1 2 7

1 3 20

2 3 3

3 1 5

4 1 9

5 6 10

It means node 1 go to node 2 with weight 7 so far so on...
And in the very beginning, i want to count the number of node , Therefore, i do the following in the map class

```
    public static class countMapper
    extends Mapper<Text,Text,Text,Text>{
    public void map(Text key, Text value, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        context.write(key, value);
        context.write(new Text(value.toString().split(" ")[0]), new Text());
    }
}
```

Also , i write the from node and to node each for once in order to count number of node.

```
    public static class countReducer
        extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text>{

        private long numNodes = 0;

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException{
            numNodes += 1;
        }

        public void cleanup(Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException{
            context.getCounter(PageRank.myCounter.numNodes).setValue(numNodes);
        }
}
```

I declare the numNodes in the Reducer Class . It seems works on counting the number of Nodes.
the result show 6 !  Correct!!
I m confused that why it works?
the map reduce isn't a distributed system to handle the problems .

Each JVM will run their reduce class. it seems the numNodes can not be counted correctly.
Because there are many reducer class. Each of the reducer class will not communicate with each others.
Therefore, I m So confused in this situation. I run it on the aws ec2 with 2 data node and 1 name node . It has shown the correct number of nodes still.

Even i create a file with 12000000 nodes to simulate the much huge size file to cause the split of file . Also , i set  mapred.reduce.tasks =2 to force multiple reducer. It still shows the correct ans.
Can Anyone tell me why?

Comment: anyone help i have stuck in this for a long time?

Comment: What do you mean by "i want to count the number of node"? The whole question needs a bit more clarity on what you actually need to do in order to provide feeback or answers.

Comment: there are number of nodes id in the input. i want to count how many number of nodes are there